# Proper use of first-last name in a obituary?

Tags: formatting, naming

I have to write my fathers obituary. I am not sure when it is proper to use a full name. We have kids, grand kids, and great grand kids. Are there rules or guidelines for using full names and what might they be if so?

Comment: You have my condolences. I hope there's someone here who can help you. Sadly, I have no experience writing obituaries, so I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 1):

It is proper to use his full name, including a well-known nickname if he had any, middle names and extensions such as Sr. For example you would get:  example Rosemary "Rose" Jean Brimson, Jr.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the rules are.

As I remember, I wrote a draft of an obituary for my grandmother that named all her children, grandchildren, and great grandchildren, but I was told to rewrite it to just give the numbers of each.

As an amateur genealogist, I think it would be helpful to future genealogists to name all the surviving members of the family, but I don't know whether the other family members want to pay for the extra words, and I don't know what the usual obituary format is for the specific newspaper or for newspapers in general.